# Why is the $1/r^2$ factor retained in Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation, potential-theory

Consider [Laplace's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation#Laplace's_spherical_harmonics) in spherical coordinates $$\nabla^2 f = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \psi^2}=0$$

Removing the $1/{r^2}$ factor on the LHS would still make the equation true, so why is it retained?

Comment: if your remove the $\frac1{r^2}$ factor in the middle term, the first '=' fails.

Comment: @achillehui I don't understand. Multiply both sides by $r^2$ and the '=' is still true for all the terms as far as I can see.

Comment: Probably because this preserves the general form of the Laplacian, and remains valid even when the right hand side is not zero, such as in Poisson's equation.

Comment: @TobErnack Yes, that's the only reason I can think of right now.